# Can I package lighttpd and my web content (HTML, CSS, JS) in to a single snap-package?

Tags: snap, lighttpd

I have gone through the snap tutorials but have been unable to understand enough to package lighttpd, configuration files and my web content into a snap-package. I would like to load on to Ubuntu server 16.04.1.

Is this possible and if so any advice on how to construct the snapcraft.yaml file?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Oh certainly! I can't speak with experience regarding the specifics of setting up lighttpd in a snap, but the [Nextcloud snap](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap) is a good example that does Apache (as well as PHP-FPM, redis, MySQL, and of course all the web code and assets).

I hope you find that helpful!